replacing a 15-amp breaker with a 20-amp breaker
My bedroom outlet is connected to the bathroom outlet and then runs into the kitchen where it's hooked into the microwave outlet. Both bedroom and bathroom are 14 gauge wire.
The wire from the bathroom is connected to the same outlet as the microwave and that wire (12 gauge) is connected to a 15-amp breaker.
When 2 appliances are being used in the bedroom on same outlet and the microwave is being used at the same time the breaker trips.
Can I increase the circuit breaker to a 20 amp or does the microwave need its own breaker? I have no more room for another breaker.


You've got Challenger breakers, which can be a BIG problem. A picture of the ENTIRE panel would help.

There are multiple ways to get more spaces that are safe. IIRC your panel (likely - we can't see what it is) is OK, the breakers in it should be replaced, wholesale before they burn down the house. Helping them burn down the house by putting a 20A breaker on 14Ga wire would not be a smart move. Not replacing all the breakers would also not be a smart move. They were recalled many years ago.

See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/267594/18078

Even though the wire at the breaker is 12g, you can't upsize the breaker because you have other wire on that circuit that is only 14g.

The size (gauge) of the conductor determines how much heat it will produce for a given amount of current. So, smaller numbered guages (thicker wires) don't get as hot. The breaker is tripping because IT is getting too hot. It's doing its job. The 12 ga wire will handle 20 amps and stay cool. The 14 will get too hot and could cause a fire. There is notthing preventing multiple appliances in you bath and bedrooms from drawing more than the 14 ga can handle.
Don't burn your house down. In some states, you will also void your insurance.

This question is similar to: Can I replace a 15 ampere circuit breaker with a 20 ampere breaker?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Read the full CPSC bulletin to see which ground fault breakers were subject to a recall. https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/1988/challenger-electrical-equipment-corp-offers-replacement-program-for-9000-gfci-circuit


when 2 appliances are being used in the bedroom on same outlet and the microwave is being used at the same time the breaker trips.

This is completely normal.  It is supposed to happen.   This is a safety protection system working to save your house from a fire, because the #14 wires in the walls were getting too hot.
Changing the breaker to 20 amps would let the wire get much too hot, and even worse, it would not stop the breaker from tripping because your microwave is 12-15 amps and your A/C is 11-12 amps, so still 23-27 amps and still overloading a 20A breaker.  You would need to install a 30A breaker or a dumb switch to stop the tripping, but then, you'd have a house fire.
The root problem is you are overloading the circuit. The cure is for you to stop overloading the circuit.
You need to look at the amp requirements of your various appliances and figure out how to stay within circuit capacity.  Or put appliances on different circuits.  Or have an electrician install additional circuits.
I see a bunch of Challenger breakers and a GE breaker.   I don't know what kind of panel it is, but you need to use breakers that are correct for the panel.  If this is a Challenger panel, that tends to confuse people because the Type C breakers  are obsolete since Challenger supposedly cheated their UL testing.  Eaton BR breakers are marked right on them "Type BR / Type C".   All the breakers wrong for the panel should be replaced with correct types, and the Challenger breakers should also be replaced. Breakers run about $7 a throw.

+1 but to be absolutely clear, the only difference between a wire and a fuse that will burn your house down is the breaker. The wires used after the breaker are sized to that breaker and not a larger one. Thus, increasing the breaker size only makes all the wires in the wall into fuses.

Firemen call that job security.
You can only use a 15 amp breaker on any circuit that has 14 gauge wire on it.
You can learn to not use so much stuff at once, or rewire that circuit to have all 12 gauge wire on it. Then you can add the 20 amp breaker.
Post another question with pictures of your panel, including the labels and we might have a way to add more circuits.  Maybe by changing some breakers to tandems or adding a sub panel.
Code has probably changed since those circuits were installed, since these days, you should have at least three circuits.  One for the bathroom, maybe one for the microwave(size matters), and the bedroom/s on another.

the breaker is 3rd from the bottom. the bedroom/bathroom/microwave all on that 15amp Breaker.  can i use a tandem 15/20 amp breaker and put the bathroom/bedroom on the 15 and the microwave on the 20.

Maybe, maybe not.  It depends too much on your panel to give a yes/no answer.  Even if you can, the 20 amp breaker cannot have 14 gauge wire on it.  It must be 12 gauge all the way to microwave or to bathroom, whichever comes first.  These days, bathrooms are suppose to be on their own 20 amp circuit.

I mean ill wire the bathroom and bedroom because there on the same wire(14 gauge) and plug that into 15-amp breaker then I might just add a sub panel for the 20 amp microwave

Also worth noting that just because you see x-gauge wire at the box and x-gauge wire at a given outlet is NOT a guarantee that less-capable gauge wire doesn't exist somewhere in the same circuit. I wouldn't upgrade any breaker without tracing every single run and junction, which mostly means I don't upgrade breakers.

I'm not an electrician, but here are some things in my mental model that help me break this down, and maybe will help for those without this basic understanding.
The gauge of a conductor has a relationship to how physically thick the conductor is. Potentially unintuitive, but the higher the gauge number, the thinner the wire. For example, 14-gauge wire (often in a white jacket) is thinner than 12-gauge wire (often in a yellow jacket). Also important to note is that the thicker the wire, the more current flow it can withstand. So a 14-gauge wire cannot carry as high of a current that a 12-gauge wire can before it gets too hot.
A 14-gauge conductor is rated to withstand up to 15 amps, whereas a 12-gauge conductor is rated to withstand up to 20 amps.
The purpose of a circuit breaker is to limit how much current can be drawn. If appliances are drawing too much current, you want the breaker to trip as a warning that you are drawing too much current. So if you install a 20 amp breaker for a circuit that has 14-gauge wire (which, as stated above, can only withstand 15 amps), then the breaker would continue to allow current draw higher than what the 14-gauge wire on that circuit could withstand.
If you have a 15 amp breaker on that circuit, the breaker will trip more often, but that is there to protect you from a fire.
In summary, I would not install a 20-amp breaker on a circuit that has 14-gauge wire. If limiting the usage of those appliances is not an option, then you should consider splitting that connected circuit into different circuits or replacing the 14-gauge wire with 12-gauge wire (in which case you can install a 20 amp breaker on that circuit). I'm not sure if these are options in your case, but maybe for the next reader of this answer.

Listen to the advice you've been given regarding a careless 20 amp increase for the convenience of not resetting breakers. Trace the circuit and verify guage.  Subpanel and dedicated run better yet. Sleeping at a hotel while your insurance and rebuild get squared away is very inconvenient.

This doesn't seem like an answer. Please take the [tour] so you understand how this site works.
